# Nginx - Nest Regex Location with a Fallback

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have an API that is reversed proxied through `Nginx`,
I'm trying to harden it so that only known paths are allowed, and add to each its own rate limit.

When nesting regex `locations`, the nesting `locations` must be regex as well, but even then I get 404 as if the nested location was not matched..

```
location  ~ ^/api/warehouse/(.*)$ {

    limit_conn warehouseConn 5;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1;
    
    location ~ ^/api/warehouse/inventory/$ {
        limit_req zone=inventory burst=10 nodelay;
    }
    
    location ~ ^/api/warehouse/pricing/$ {
        limit_req zone=pricing burst=5 nodelay;
    }
    
    location ~ /{
        #fallback for blocking any unmatched location
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The 404 is probably because the location **was** matched. The `proxy_pass` is **not** inherited into nested locations.

Comment: @RichardSmith so if I want to set a diffrent rate limit to every sub location and proxy pass it all to server, what is the recommended way to write that kind of conf?

Comment: You could put a `proxy_pass` statement in each `location` block. Either capture `$1` in the nested location, or replace it with text.